# why e4 rcp application is locked in windows XP and not launching for other users in same machine

Tags: locking, swt, workspace, e4

I have developed a e4 RCP aplication.
While launching the application, creating a folder "workspace" and inside that /.metadata/.lock
So when i switch user, i am getting a error that already one user is using/locked your application and can't run.

Error: C:\Program Files.....\workspace.metadata.lock(Access denied)

But i need to run my application to multiple user support in XP

I have this issue only in XP. in vista,windows7 and windows 8 working fine

Any help or workaround to run the the application after the user switch(which is running in other user)?

**Update**

I have done this by adding below line in my product file, which will take care of launching the application in user workspace

```
<launcherArgs>
<programArgsWin>-data @user.home/workspace</programArgsWin>
</launcherArgs>
```

Comment: Only one RCP instance can access the workspace at a time, so on everything except XP you must be getting a separate workspace for each user

Comment: @greg-449 yeah, for all other OS creating workspace in %localappdata%/virtualstore/ except XP. But how to solve this issue in XP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this works on XP but you could try setting the workspace to be in the user's home directory. You can do this in the 'LifeCycle' '@PostContextCreate' method:

```java
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate()
{
  final Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();

  // TODO instanceLoc will be null if user specifies -data @none option

  // TODO instanceLoc.isSet() will be true if user specifies -data path

  // Set the default

  final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "workspace name");   

  instanceLoc.set(path.toUri().toURL(), false);
```